# VBA Excel Macro to update cell values based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

It is impossible for me to solve this, im at my boiling points upper limit, so i could really use your directions or help. I've attached an image in the header. I need a vba macro to update / change the values in column E ( Ve Planning ) with the following contitions:

1. Column D must be blank.
2. Must update only for the same values in column A.
3. Column I ( Operation ) = LASER.
4. If column F ( W NO ) values are equal.

Then update the column E value for Operation = SUDURA with column E value for operation LASER + 10 days.

[image]

I dont know if you understand this mess, but if you do, any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks alot!

Comment: could you please elaborate the requirement and show your code attempts and explain why they don't solve your need?

Comment: Hello! this is a schedulling logic so to speak, means that for each production order ( colum A ) wich has no finished qty posted in column D and has the next operation SUDURA ( column I ) in the same week ( column F ) as the operation LASER, then the value from column E must be the value from column E for operation LASER + 10 days. its a sequence of operations and being in the same week its a constraint. my code attempts are pathetic, as i'm a total newbie.

Comment: please edit your question with this new info in your comment, and post your code as well.

Comment: @CatalinCernat , I think you have a Type error in your attached table. In your 4th row of data, in "Description" should be "BRAS EXTREMITE AX 36-39" , like the row above, right ?

Comment: Perhaps listen to @PA.. This task is really quite simple and we'd be happy to assist you. However, we like to match our effort with your own. If you post at least something that you have tried, then you will likely receive a full answer minutes from your posting. If you don't  then people are far less likely  to respond.

Comment: its embarrasing, but this is all the code that my stupid brain got so far:   `code` Sub Update()
    For i = 2 To 1000
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            If .Range("I" & i).Value = .Range("I" & i).Value Then _
            .Range("E" & i).Value = .Range("E" & i).Value + 10 Else .Range("E" & i).Value = .Range("E" & i).Value
        End With
    Next i
End Sub `code` thanks alot for your kind advices.

Comment: post your code by editing your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the short code below, it worked in my test with limited Data records. Let me know if it works on your data as well.

```
Sub UpdateVEPlanning()


Dim sht                                 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow, lRow                       As Long

' modify "Sheet1" to whatever worksheet name you have
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' find last row in sheet with data
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For lRow = 2 To LastRow

    If sht.Cells(lRow, 1) = sht.Cells(lRow - 1, 1) Then
        If Not (sht.Cells(lRow, 9).Find("SUDURA") Is Nothing) And (IsEmpty(sht.Cells(lRow, 4).Value2) Or sht.Cells(lRow, 4).Value2 <= 0) Then
            If sht.Cells(lRow, 6) = sht.Cells(lRow - 1, 6) Then
                sht.Cells(lRow, 5) = sht.Cells(lRow - 1, 5) + 10
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: it works...like a charm. im trying now to understand what you did. thanks a million. can I ask more question regarding the logic of your code if i dont understand it?

Comment: @CatalinCernat sure

Comment: what if the column A has values that are not in order, for example between the FPO120000 there's a different value. as i tried to understand your code sets the value for column E only if the previous row has the same value in column A, right? lRow - 1? so the data must be in blocks consisting of the same values in column A it cannot be intertwined.

Comment: @CatalinCernat you can just sort the entire table before you run this code. Sort that table by Column A, then Column l.