# Excel VBA Macro to change empty fields in a column to 'checked' (String) based on various search criterias

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am really new to VBA Macros and would appreciate any help on this matter.

I need to write a macro to change the value of a column to 'checked' based on different search criterias. My requirement is that one of the columns values must be automatically marked as checked based on search criterias which will search for existence of serial nos contained in a string in one column inside string values of other columns.

Please help me in creating a macro to accomplish this task.

I am sorry to say that I cannot share the code or attach a screenshot to further explain the scenario because of confidentiality reasons.

Detailed explaination

Column to be modified : Comments (initially blank)

Columns used for search criteria : Can be any column in the existing table.

Search criteria:

- A substring from the reference column (basically a number with 6 digits will be selected as the search key)

Note : There is no specific format followed by this column (and we can do nothing about that) eg: In one column the entry will be 35567890-DEF-GHJ while in another it will be like Ref:35567890-- and in another column field it will be like CEK 35567890.

- The substring must be checked not only for the entries in the same coulmn but with the contents of the entire table. Basically it is like the find function in the excel.
- If a match is found I need to add up the values in the debit and credit entries and see whether the result is 0. If the result is zero, I need to enter 'checked' in the comments field that allows string values.

Comment: Dear friends, Please post the reason for why you downvoted a question. People ask questions in stack hoping for answer to solve their issues. This question may seem dumb to you. But the people who posts the question doesnt think so and they may be actually dying to find a solution. Kindly state the reason for downvote before you do. bec it may result in taking longer time for our question to answered and I request you to kindly wait until someone gives correct answer to the question because an answer is what really matters. Appreciate your kind understanding on this matter.

Comment: Your Question does not contain any code.Please edit your question and add the code you've tried. So that your fellow SO'ers can help you with your troubles

Comment: I can't be sure, but I would guess that the dv is due to the complete lack of code in the question.  Your request is "Please help me as on how to modify the existing macro to incorporate this change." which is impossible to do without seeing the existing macro.  I'm surprised the question has only received **one** downvote.

Comment: @YowE3K Thankyou for sharing the reason. I have edited my code accordingly. I am not really concerned about the downvote, but I really need help in this question and no one have answered it yet and I assumed that it is because of the downvote.

Comment: @SivaprasathV Thankyou for sharing the reason. I am sorry but I am not allowed to share the code of existing macro do to some reasons. But I can assure you that the code has nothing to do with my question. It is a completely different function I am trying to implement.

Comment: In Stackoverflow you can ask someone to help you with the errors in your code. You cant ask us write a code for you.

Comment: @eccentricCoder - Without the code, no-one will be **able** to suggest modifications.  If you can't share the code, you will need to make the modifications without help.

Comment: @SivaprasathV Please understand that this is the first day I had the requirement to work in macro. I am really helpless here. I have seen other posts ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067787/vba-excel-macro-to-update-cell-values-based-on-multiple-criteria?rq=1# )asking for help with out any code but explaining the scenario. I hoped that someone will be able to help. I dont need you to write the code for me. I am not expecting that and havn't provided any fields for that purpose either. I am a JD & completely new to VB. If this question needs to be deleted please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not one complete macro but still does the work.

Macros where used only for extracting the product code. For the remaining processes I used existing functions as in, performed a comparing function on the net amount and then used a simple if to mark the column as check.

Macro used for extracting product code.

```
Public Function getProductCode(source As String) As String

Dim rExp As Object, allMatches As Object, match As Object
Dim result As String: result = ""



Set rExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With rExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "(?:^|\D)(\d{7,8})(?!\d)"
End With


Set allMatches = rExp.Execute(source)
For Each match In allMatches
    result = result + match.SubMatches.Item(0)
Next
    getProductCode = result
End Function
```

A new column 'Reference' was then created on which the macro was used passing the specific column and the extracted product code is stored here.

After this a function was used to find duplicate entries and sum up the total number of products sold. The formula I used is as follows:

```
=ROUND(SUMIFS([Total],[Reference],[@Reference]),2)=0
```

Finally I used a simple if to mark the column as checked if the previously generated result (in column status) is true.

```
=IF([@Column1]=TRUE, "Checked", "")
```

This is how I got it done.

There might be better way to do it. But if anyone else is facing the same problem this will help.